# Netbeans CSS not hinting all properties

Tags: css, netbeans

Why doesn't NetBeans give you all hints when you write code? For example:
"display:" gives you hints such as, block, inline, but not grid or flexbox. 
Do I need to install plugins to get this to work? I'm using Netbeans version 8.2.

Comment: AFAIK for that feature (auto suggestions) you need to wait until [Apache Foundation releases Netbeans 9](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65873923). Till then use VSCode , Sublime Text, Atom or Adobe Brackets.

Answer (score 3):

There is no plugin to install and you make a good point; it is certainly reasonable to expect that values such as **flex** and **grid** are offered.

The problem exists in 8.2 but also in the beta version of NetBeans 9. I doubt that this will ever be addressed for releases prior to 9, but I have raised a bug report asking that the **display** values provided for code completion additionally include those specified in [the w3c documentation for **display**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/):

- flow
- flow-root
- flex
- grid
- subgrid
- ruby-base-container
- ruby-text-container
- contents
- inline-flex
- inline-grid

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-445

Comment: This bug is still not addressed, does anyone have found a way around?

Comment: @nicolallias You are right. I just checked, and the problem persists in NetBeans 11.2. I just updated [the bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-445) to reflect that. The only solutions I can think of are [1] Wait for the bug to be fixed. [2] [Volunteer your services, and you can write the code fix](http://netbeans.apache.org/participate/submit-pr.html) to NetBeans 11.2 yourself!