# Unexpected character(s) warning in netbeans

Tags: css, netbeans, warnings

I'm getting several warnings in netbeans in my css stylesheet from code copied from bootstrap

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px
}
```

The touch-action, and user-select properties (the ones AFTER the css prefix) are showing the warning underlining the property with the "Unknown property touch-action" warning

And for the perspective property is underlining the value "1000px" (also after the ones with te css prefix).

I want to know how to rewrite the property it in a correct way so it doesn't pop the warning.
I know i can make rules on my netbeans so it doesn't trigger the warning but i dont want that. I'm pretty sure there must exist a syntax that the IDE takes as valid.

I've been able to fix similar issue like

```
text-align: start;// shows warning

text-align: start right;// NO WARNING HERE
```

Comment: These are new properties and values, it's possible that your version of Netbeans just doesn't support them. Check the documentation.

Comment: I think you should NOT hack Bootstrap rules in order to suppress a warning. You will be tied to the current version of the design then. Instead, just ignore those warnings or make sure that NetBeans is not showing them.

Comment: @LajosArpad im not hacking bootstrap, i liked the css bootstrap applies to a button so i copied that style instead of importing entire library. It shows warnings, and I want to correct those. Ignoring warnings is not a solution for correcting warnings

Comment: @Paulie_D do you know where to find a list of supported css properties for netbeans 8.2? I cant find it anywhere

Comment: Nope, sorry...I'd assume his would be in the documentation.

Comment: Mbotet, the warning is a bug in NetBeans and not in the code. I acknowledge that you are not hacking Bootstrap, but even without doing so, this approach makes no sense.

Comment: If you can explain what doesnt make sense to you maybe it helps me understand where im going wrong. Thanks

Comment: [1] You are not doing anything wrong. As @LajosArpad pointed out, this is a bug in NetBeans for which I have already raised a bug report. See [NETBEANS-445 Many missing values for code completion of the CSS display property](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-445). NetBeans hasn't kept up with enhancements to CSS, but your code should still work. [2] There are similar questions to yours on SO such as [Netbeans CSS not hinting all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49052178/2985643) and [netbeans 8.2 css grid warnings and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51021631/2985643).

Comment: Mbotet you have a correct CSS and NetBeans should not warn you. There is nothing to be fixed. It doesn't make sense to adapt to the bugs NetBeans has. NetBeans is just a software and has bugs as virtually all software. The solution to the problem you experience is to let those who are responsible for NetBeans know about this problem so they can fix it. @skomisa has already made that step. Hopefully a new release or patch in the not too distant future will solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, clear enough for me now. I was doubting just that because i overestimated the IDE and underestimated myself.  I already read what @skomisa is offering, and were helpful, but with other tags so wasnt sure at all about which ones were right and which weren't. Thanks!